# Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, description, calories})

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
  import React from 'react'

  const desserts = [
    {
      title: 'Chocolate Cake',
      description: 'Chocolate cake is a cake flavored with melted chocolate',
      calories: 500,
    },
    {
        title: 'Chocolate Cake',
        description: 'Chocolate cake is a cake flavored with melted chocolate',
        calories: 500,
      }
  ];
  const CourseraList = () => {
    
    const newDesserts= desserts.map((dessert) => {
        return {
            ...dessert,
            title: dessert.title.toUpperCase(),
            kCal: dessert.calories / 1000,
        }
    })
    return (
      <div>
        {newDesserts}
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default CourseraList
```

Why is it showing error?
I am returning an object.

Error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys `{title, description, calories}`). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: It's showing an error _because_ you're returning an object (which, _as the error message tells you_, isn't a valid React child, but you're trying to use it as one anyway).

Comment: Whats the correct way to do this?

Comment: You have to use one by one like 
```html
<div>
      <p>Title: {newDesserts.title}</p>
      <p>Description: {newDesserts.description}</p>
      <p>Calories: {newDesserts.calories}</p>
</div>
``` with map function of course.

Comment: [Objects are not valid as a React child](https://www.google.com/search?q=Objects+are+not+valid+as+a+React+child+site:stackoverflow.com) - pick your answer from any of these.

Comment: The correct way is to return something that is valid as a React child, or don't try to use it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to render an array of objects directly within JSX, which is not allowed in React. React expects JSX to represent components or primitive values, not plain objects.

```
import React from 'react';

const desserts = [
  {
    title: 'Chocolate Cake',
    description: 'Chocolate cake is a cake flavored with melted chocolate',
    calories: 500,
  },
  {
    title: 'Chocolate Cake',
    description: 'Chocolate cake is a cake flavored with melted chocolate',
    calories: 500,
  },
];

const CourseraList = () => {
  const newDesserts = desserts.map((dessert, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
      <p>Title: {dessert.title}</p>
      <p>Description: {dessert.description}</p>
      <p>Calories: {dessert.calories}</p>
    </div>
  ));

  return <div>{newDesserts}</div>;
};

export default CourseraList;
```

Answer (score -1):

Error says, use like this. Sorry for fast answer, I don't have so much time to detail rn.

```
  import React from 'react'

  const desserts = [
    {
      title: 'Chocolate Cake',
      description: 'Chocolate cake is a cake flavored with melted chocolate',
      calories: 500,
    },
    {
        title: 'Chocolate Cake',
        description: 'Chocolate cake is a cake flavored with melted chocolate',
        calories: 500,
      }
  ];
  const CourseraList = () => {
    
    const newDesserts= desserts.map((dessert) => {
        return <>
                   <p>dessert.title</p>
               </>
    })
    return (
      <div>
        {newDesserts}
      </div>
    )
  }
  
  export default CourseraList
```